# Convergence of a Function Question

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Does there exist a function whose local or absolute minima is greater than 1 such that its integral from 0 to infinity converges?

Comment: The integral of that function from 0 to infinity does not converge...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of function isn't possible If you want absolute (global) minima to be 1. Since :

$$f(x)\ge 1\implies \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)\mathrm dx\ge  \int_{0}^{\infty} 1 \mathrm dx \to \infty$$

Therefore clearly, $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)\mathrm dx$ diverges.

Though, such function can be constructed in such a way that it's local minima is $1$, and it's integral from $0$ to $\infty$ converges.

For example, 
$$f(x)=$$
\begin{cases}
0 & x\le -3\\
x+3 & -3<x\le -1\\
-x+1 & -1<x\le 0\\
x+1 & 0<x\le 1\\
-x+3 & 1<x\le 2\\
0 & x>3\\
\end{cases}

[image]

Comment: Can someone explain the reason for downvote?