# Functional Convergence Question Revised

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

[Convergence of a Function Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2385185/convergence-of-a-function-question?noredirect=1#comment4918258_2385185)

Since I didn't get an answer for this question, I ask now, does there exist a function whose:

limit as x approaches infinity is greater than 1, whose local or absolute minima is 1, and whose integral from 0 to infinity converges

Comment: You did get an answer, you just won't like it. And the answer is "no", again, for the same reason: the integral can't converge, if the function approaches a non-zero value at infinity.

Comment: @ProfessorVector No, he isn't lying, I posted an answer 4 minutes after this very question was posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. If $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$ and $L\ne0$, then $\int_0^\infty f(t)\ dt$ does not converge.

To see this, suppose without loss of generality that $L>0$. Since $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$, there exists $M>0$ such that $f(x)>L/2$ for all $x>M$. Then $\int_M^\infty f(t)\ dt \geq \int_M^\infty (L/2)\ dt = \infty$ shows that
$\int_0^\infty f(t)\ dt$ diverges.

Similarly, we cannot have a function whose absolute minimum is $1$ be integrable. However, the function
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
x+1 & \text{if}\ 0 \leq x <1,\\
-x+3 & \text{if}\ 1\leq x < 3,\\
0 & \text{if}\ 3 \leq x,
\end{cases}
$$
has a local minimum of $1$ at $x=0$, and
$$
\int_0^\infty f(t)\ dt = \int_0^3 f(t)\ dt = 3.5
$$
converges.